# Move data from snowflake to aws elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking into moving data from snowflake to elasticsearch.
What is the easiest way to do so?

We receive some data into Azure data lake from some other source. This data in ADLS is then moved to Snowflake using pipelines.

I've written a python script to load data from Snowflake to ElasticSearch and have been successful in pulling data from Snowflake and loading it into Elasticsearch.

What I now need is to automate this process of moving data from Snowflake to Elasticsearch.

What is the easiest way to do so?
Can Azure Data Factory pipelines be used for the same? What connector can I use for Elasticsearch?

Or can Azure functions help with this?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you've already written a python script that does what you want, what's stopping you from scheduling this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using Logstash jdbc input. Here is an example Logstash conf for `input jdbc:snowflake` and `output elasticsearch`.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\ELKStack\logstash-8.8.1-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.8.1\logstash-core\lib\jars\snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2-javadoc.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:snowflake://*******.uae-north.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH"
    jdbc_user => "<username>"
    jdbc_password => "<password>"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER LIMIT 10;"
  }
}

filter{}

output
{
  elasticsearch
  {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    user => "<username>"
    password => "<password>"
    index =>"snowflakelog_index"
  }
}
```

Also check this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/snowflake-to-elasticsearch-using-logtsash/341785

Comment: Thank you!  Actually I went ahead with the function activity of ADF to move the data.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to hear you solved.